# Can you use TPL Dataflow to propogate a message only when a condition is true?

Tags: c#, dataflow

```
var ints = Enumerable.Range( 0, 10 ).ToList();
var source = new BufferBlock<int>();
var action = new ActionBlock<int>( async (i) => { Console.WriteLine( "Processing i" ); await Task.Delay(i*1000);}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 } );
```

Is it possible to use TPL Dataflow so that ActionBlock only pulls from bufferblock if the sum of all i's being processed <= 10. So first pass would process 1, 2, 3, 4; then 5 would pull as soon as a combined total of 5 is freed up?

Comment: Like a counting semaphore?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica No.